# Who has privileges to see user's OpenId's?

Tags: support, security

Do any of the privileges/badges/mods on **Stack Overflow enable people to see other users' open IDs**?

*I created a unique email to access SO and it was recently attempted at being cracked, you know when you login to gmail and your asked to verify yourself with a sms number..  ie "someone attempted logging in to your email that many times (brute force) we're asking you to verify yourself (now that you know the password) via the existing mobile number listed..."*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Diamond moderators and the Developers. According to all the theory, these are the people who has the highest level of trust from the community.

However there isn't much we can do with the information, since we still need your password and info to be able to login to your account. Also the information isn't extremely valuable when troubleshooting problems on the SE network. Specifically Google OpenId links are useless to us, since they are obscured and ends up leading to nowhere.

There is no level of reputation that will give you this information when looking at a profile other then the above.

Comment: +1 yeah, I haven't received any other type of spam, so I can confirm the source isn't SO.